# Significance of Linux kernel's default_console_loglevel

Tags: linux, kernel, proc, debugging

What is the significance of `default_console_loglevel` in Linux? Commonly I see it described as the default value of `console_loglevel`. However, what that means I haven't seen explained anywhere.

Besides, on my as well as most ohter systems I have checked, the values of four log variables are

```
 [root@localhost printk]# cat /proc/sys/kernel/printk
4   4   1   7
```

Since I haven't changed anything the `console_loglevel`(4) should have been equal to `default_consolle loglevel`(7), which it isn't. So what exactly is the use/significance of `default_console_loglevel`?

Answer (score 3):

Short answser: you either have `loglevel=4` set in the kernel command line (check with `cat /proc/cmdline`) or maybe have something like an init script that executes `echo 4 > /proc/sys/kernel/printk` (or equivalent).

In both cases, `default_console_loglevel` is overridden.

---

Long answer:

When you read `/proc/sys/kernel/printk`, four numbers are returned. These are defined in the kernel in [printk.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6.15/source/include/linux/printk.h#L62) as the elements in the array `int console_printk[4]` which is **initialized** at compile time (in [printk.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6.15/source/kernel/printk/printk.c#L63)), but this array can be modified at runtime.

These values are:

- `console_loglevel` (or `console_printk[0]`).
- `default_message_loglevel` (or `console_printk[1]`).
- `minimum_console_loglevel` (or `console_printk[2]`).
- `default_console_loglevel` (or `console_printk[3]`).

`console_loglevel` (`console_printk[0]`) is the most important one: it is the *current* value of console message priority level.

What this means is that, at any point in time `printk` is called in kernel code (this also applies to [`pr_warn`, `pr_info`, etc.](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6.15/source/include/linux/printk.h#L286)), the corresponding priority level is compared at runtime and if it is strictly lower than the current `console_loglevel`, it does get printed to console. For example, if it is set to 5 (i.e. [KERN_WARNING](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6.15/source/include/linux/kern_levels.h#L8)), only priorities with values 4 (`KERN_ERR`) or lower are directly printed to console.

This is the only value that makes sense to be modified, so when you write with e.g. `echo 5 > /proc/sys/kernel/printk` you are setting `console_loglevel` to 5.

`console_loglevel` is compile-time initialized as `CONSOLE_LOGLEVEL_DEFAULT`, which is exactly the same as `default_console_loglevel` (or `console_printk[3]`). `default_console_loglevel` is therefore the default value for `console_loglevel` at boot time. This is set via kernel compile-time configuration (Kconfig), which defines `CONFIG_CONSOLE_LOGLEVEL_DEFAULT`.

To make this runtime-configurable (so there's no need to recompile the kernel) there is another mechanism to set this boot-time default value: if `loglevel=x` (where `x` is a number) is passed as part of the kernel command line, then `console_loglevel` gets initialized to `x`. Note that `default_console_loglevel` never gets modified, so, in this case, it is just silently ignored and overridden.

For completeness, the other two values are:

- `default_message_loglevel` (or `console_printk[1]`): this is the default value for `printk` commands with no specified priority. This is set via Kconfig (`CONFIG_MESSAGE_LOGLEVEL_DEFAULT`). It cannot be modified after compilation.
- `minimum_console_loglevel` (or `console_printk[2]`): this is the minimum priority value. It is hardcoded to 1 and cannot be modified.

---

Note: this is an answer to a 4-year question that no one had answered, this is likely no longer of use to the question author but this was my first Google search result, so this is hopefully useful to someone else.